# Django: increment the counter of another model when an entry occurs

Tags: django, django-models, count

how can we increment the counter when an entry occurs in the comments Class???

```
class Status(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    counter = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Comments(models.Model):
    status = models.ForeignKey(status)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=140)
```

Comment: `IntegerField` doesn't take `max_length`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either by using a [signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/) or adding it to the processing method of (saving) comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can override your save method

```
class Comments(models.Model):
   status = models.ForeignKey(status)
   comment = models.CharField(max_length=140)

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
         #get the status 
         #save it

         #Call super save to store your comment
         super(Comments, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```